# Is it possible to intercept providers in Nest.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, interceptor, nestjs

I'm trying to [intercept](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors) Nest.js [providers](https://docs.nestjs.com/providers) and it doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone confirm this? If yes, is there any specific design reason for that?

Usually it's possible to intercept any `bean` in dependency injection containers.

Comment: can you give an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Hello @shusson. Imagine you have a controller method that calls two different providers (each one triggers a different remote call) and you want to measure the performance of each provider separately, using let's say a MonitoringInterceptor. So you would annotate each provider with @UseInterceptors(MonitoringInterceptor) and expect to collect metrics on both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Kamil wrote in this [issue](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1923#issuecomment-479430378):

> it's impossible

In this [issue](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/615#issuecomment-385619855), he gives the following explanation:

> because it could break too many existing codebases

---

But of course, you can always create your own [custom decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html) that also work on any class methods to enable aspect-oriented programming on providers.